# agregar dato a un objeto jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, objeto

Buen dia,

Tengo el siguiente objeto que enviaré por ajax, valores leidos de inputs que no vienen al caso

```
var datos=
    {
      "id_usuario_logueado":id_usuario_logueado,
      "id_producto":id_producto,
      "fecha_pedido":fecha_pedido,
      "nombre_cliente":nombre_cliente,
      "id_clasificacion_pedido":id_clasificacion_pedido
    }
```

tengo que capturar los contenidos de varios inputs, son tallas de zapatos del 21 al 43, asi que no quisiera hacerlo uno por uno y armar el array que muestro arriba con las tallas, quisiera leerlos en un for y luego agregarlos al array

estos son los inputs

```
<label>21</label><input id="input_talla_21_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>22</label><input id="input_talla_22_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>23</label><input id="input_talla_23_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>24</label><input id="input_talla_24_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>25</label><input id="input_talla_25_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>26</label><input id="input_talla_26_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>                        
                            <label>27</label><input id="input_talla_27_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>28</label><input id="input_talla_28_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>29</label><input id="input_talla_29_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>30</label><input id="input_talla_30_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>31</label><input id="input_talla_31_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>32</label><input id="input_talla_32_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>33</label><input id="input_talla_33_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>34</label><input id="input_talla_34_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>35</label><input id="input_talla_35_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>36</label><input id="input_talla_36_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>                      
                            <label>37</label><input id="input_talla_37_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>38</label><input id="input_talla_38_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>39</label><input id="input_talla_39_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>40</label><input id="input_talla_40_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>41</label><input id="input_talla_41_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>42</label><input id="input_talla_42_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
                            <label>43</label><input id="input_talla_43_modal_crear_pedido" class="input_pequeno"></input>
```

como todos los inputs tienen el id input_talla_21_modal_crear_pedido, solo cambia el numero de la talla, entonces los recorro en un for asi, desde el 21 hasta el 43

```
    for(var i = 21; i < 44 ; i++)
      {
        var cantidad = $("#input_talla_"+i+"_modal_crear_pedido").val();
        if (cantidad == "")
        {
          //si el input esta vacio, cantidad será 0
          cantidad = 0;
        }
//aqui me muestra efectivamente las tallas y sus respectivas cantidades sin problemas
        console.log("talla"+i+":"+cantidad);
    
    
    //aqui se supone que agrego un valor nuevo al objeto de arriba, pero no me funciona
//si no pongo +i solo me agrega 1 talla, suponque es por que se llama igual en cada iteracion
        datos.talla+i = cantidad;
      }
```

lo que quisiera al final seria esto

```
var datos=
    {
      "id_usuario_logueado":id_usuario_logueado,
      "id_producto":id_producto,
      "fecha_pedido":fecha_pedido,
      "nombre_cliente":nombre_cliente,
      "id_clasificacion_pedido":id_clasificacion_pedido,
      "talla21":5,
      "talla22":3,
      "talla23":0,
      "talla24":0,
      "talla25":5,

       etc etc hasta 42
    }
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los inputs comparten una clase, cada uno individualmente tiene un `value` solo falta que cada uno identifique univocamente la talla. De esa manera podrías hacer todo de una sola vez. Algo asi:

```js
const talles_y_cantidades = $(".input_pequeno").map((e, i)=> ({talla:i.id,cantidad:+i.value})).get();

console.log(talles_y_cantidades);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>21</label><input id="21" class="input_pequeno"></input>
<label>22</label><input id="22" class="input_pequeno" value="1"></input>
<label>23</label><input id="23" class="input_pequeno"></input>
<label>24</label><input id="24" class="input_pequeno"></input>
```

Comment: super bien! lo logré hacer como me respondí pero no sabia esto, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

ya pude, lo hice de la siguiente manera en el for

datos["talla"+i] = cantidad;